# Tuple with const noncopyable element

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, tuples, visual-c++-2010

I need to create a `std::tuple<const XYZ,...>` where XYZ is **not copyable**. Is something like that even possible? My current code

```
auto test() -> std::tuple<const XYZ> { return std::make_tuple(XYZ()); }
```

leads to C2248 in Visual Studio 2010... Which I find quite dubious as I'm constructing the tuple with an R-Value, so I'd assume that move-construction would kick in...

Comment: [This](http://liveworkspace.org/code/cd8c16cb4e76b3602ebc37074d6238f3) compiles fine with VC++ 2012; if it doesn't with VC++ 2010 then chalk it up to a compiler bug (and upgrade your compiler ;-]).

Comment: Maybe try `std::forward_as_tuple` as a work-around.

Comment: @Xeo : Oops, mistagged, thanks for correcting.

Comment: @ildjarn: This has nothing to do with the IDE itself, can we let that one out? :P Added the specific VC++ version instead.

Comment: @Xeo : `visual-c++` + `visual-studio-xxxx` is generally how I tag VC++ version-specific questions, since no one uses the `visual-c++-xxxx` tags. :-P

Comment: `gcc 4.7.1` barks on this too even if the type is move constructible.

Comment: @ildjarn: Hmmm.... oh well, then I'll just don't touch it anymore then. :)

Comment: @ildjarn: your XYZ is copyable.

Comment: @n.m. : Very good point, I totally missed that. :-P [This updated testcase](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1dc9048776259a886f8999b1bdcb502f) compiles cleanly in VC++ 2012, but fails with GCC 4.7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the element is both noncopyable and `const`.  The `const XYZ` element behaves as a `const XYZ` member; by 5.2.5p4 accessing the `const XYZ` element on an xvalue will yield an xvalue with union cv qualification i.e. having effective type `const XYZ &&`.  That type is not suitable as an argument to the move constructor of `XYZ` so the deleted/private copy constructor will be attempted to be called instead.

Another way of looking at it is that a move constructor (e.g. the move constructor of `std::tuple<...>`) is obliged to ensure that its argument is left in an unspecified but *valid* state.  By making the element `const` you've said that the only valid state for that element is the state it's constructed with, so the move constructor is not allowed to move from it, *even if* it is contained in an xvalue.

A workaround would be to define a *const move* constructor and `const_cast` its argument to delegate to the move constructor:

```
XYZ(const XYZ &&xyz): XYZ(const_cast<XYZ &&>(xyz)) {}
```

Amusingly, with gcc-4.7.2 it's enough to just *declare* the const move constructor; by RVO the actual call to the const move constructor can be elided.  Don't rely on this.